# Inside a Docker container, `tini` should be proxying signals to my Java app, but it doesn't seem to be doing so

Tags: bash, docker, signals, init

I'm using `tini` as my init process to allow me to launch a Java app via a shell script in a container and have my app get signals from Docker when the container is stopped.  Given that the problem exhibits itself well by just showing what is in the process list inside the container, I'll be brief in terms of my setup.

I have a shell script `startup.sh` that needs to be run to set up things for my Java app.  It does that setup and then runs the app. Normally, the script launches Java in the foreground.  For debugging, I have the script launch my Java app in the background and then start a bash shell.  I see the same problematic behavior either way.

I have these two lines in my Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "-g", "--"]
CMD ["./bin/startup.sh"]
```

At the bottom of the startup.sh script, my Java app is launched via:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005 -Dfilethis.root.dir=/home/fetch/fetchbase -jar bin/fetch.jar
```

I have always known that bash will not transparently forward signals.  Googling for a solution, I found `tini`.  From what I read, if I use the `-g` option to `tini`, then it should forward signals not only to its direct child process but also to processes launched by that child process due to them all being in the same process group.

When I use the debug mode to get a shell inside the container, here's what I see in the process list:

```
sh-4.2$ ps -ae -o pid,ppid,gid,cmd
  PID  PPID   GID CMD
    1     0  1000 /tini -g -- ./bin/startup.sh
    8     1  1000 /bin/sh ./bin/startup.sh
   16     8  1000 /usr/bin/Xvfb :15 -screen 0 1280x1024x24
   42     1     0 /usr/sbin/sshd
   44     8  1000 java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005 -Dfilethis.root.dir=/home/fetch/fetchbase -jar bin/fetch.jar
   45     8  1000 /bin/sh
   63    45  1000 ps -ae -o pid,ppid,gid,cmd
```

This looks right.  p#1 `tini` launched p#8, my shell script, which launched p#44, my Java app.  All three processes are in the same process group with id 1000.

I put the debugger on my Java process, and set breakpoints at a few places in teardown code...code that will run when the app gets a TERM signal.   then I run one of two commands:

```
1) kill -TERM 1

2) kill -TERM 44
```

In the first case, the case that would apply if Docker was shutting down the container (right?), my breakpoints aren't hit in my app and the container dies immediately.  Logging I've put in my app confirms that my teardown code never ran.  Shouldn't `tini` be passing the TERM signal to my Java app in this case?

In the second case, my breakpoints are hit in my debugger and the logs show that my teardown code ran.

I get the same behavior when my Java app is run in the foreground by my shell script at container launch, and then I do `docker stop` on the container...my breakpoints and teardown code don't get hit.

What am I missing?  Am I misinterpreting what `tini` does in terms of propagating signals? TIA!

Comment: I seem to have the same problem recently. The setup used to work, but now it no longer works. Looks like something broke, but I did not have the chance to look into it yet.

Comment: For me it turned out that it was not a Docker problem, but a pure JVM problem not shutting down because of remaining non-daemon Threads, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74874740/1747140 - not sure if its related to your problem

Comment: Your startup script is unclear. How do you run `java`, note that if the command (e.g `java ...`) is not prefixed by `exec` then the shell that ran the script will still be the parent, and as such don't forward signals. So that's possibly what you're seeing there.